# Google Maps API : Requesting and recieving json data for geolocation

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, geolocation

I want to get the physical location (lat and long) on the basis of MAC address via Google Maps Geolocation api in javascript.

As per the documentation of Google Maps API, for geolocation, the information must be in json format  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#body requested to the given url on which it returns the data in json https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#responses

I have tried this piece of javascript code:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_API_KEY";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json.location.lat+","+json.location.lng+","+json.accuracy);
    }
}
var data = JSON.stringify({
                "wifiAccessPoints": [
                    {
                        "macAddress": "MY_MAC_ADDRESS"
                    },
                    {
                        "macAddress": "MY_MAC_ADDRESS"
                    }
                ]
            });

xhr.send(data);
```

But I get the following error in the console

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_API_KEY 403()
```

Anything wrong with the code? Or is there another better method?

**NOTE:** You might ask why not simply use `navigator.geolocation`? Well, because the system on which I am building my project does not support HTML5 geolocation api.

Answer (score 0):

The **error(403)** that you get based on the [documention](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#errors) is **dailyLimitExceeded** or **userRateLimitExceeded**. The reason is you've exceeded the requests per second per user limit that you configured in the Google Developers Console. This limit should be configured to prevent a single or small group of users from exhausting your daily quota, while still allowing reasonable access to all users.

For more information and on how to check the Usage or Quotas that you use in your Google Developers Console, follow the guidelines on this [page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158858).